# How to properly bend a note in an audio synthesis application?

Tags: c#, audio, sound-synthesis

**Problem**

I'm trying to figure this out for a while to no avail - how to continuously change the pitch of a note between two frequencies.

I'm generating the audio signal with a function similar to this:

```cs
double SineGenerator(double time, double frequency)
{
    return Math.Sin(frequency * time * 2 * Math.PI);
}
```

While I manage time manually outside of this function, like so:

```
time += 1.0 / sampleRate;
double sample = SineGenerator(time, frequency);
```

And the obvious solution of linearly interpolating the `frequency` parameter over the desired amount of samples does not work as expected. The sound wave gets filled with pops and clicks when doing this.

How must I implement this instead?

**Solution (Edit)**

Thanks to geofftnzless, this was surprisingly easy to solve. I have switched to using this generator now:

```
double SineGenerator(ref double time, double frequency, int sampleRate)
{
    return Math.Sin(time += (frequency * 2 * Math.PI) / sampleRate);
}
```

Which takes care of incrementing `time` internally.

Using this generator interpolating `frequency` works smoothly and with not audible problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of multiplying `frequency` by `time`, use `frequency` to increment `time` by the appropriate amount. That way `time` is continuous and you wont get jumps.

Comment: I.e. `Sin(time + frequency)` (which I believe would normally be called a *phase*, not a frequency)? In that case, what's the "appropriate amount"? I need control over the pitch of each note, and using the sine wave function above, the frequency parameter lets me do that in a straightforward way. I have no clue how I would be able to control the sound's frequency by changing its phase (or if that's even possible).

Comment: No, I mean keep track of the `time` for each generator, and go `time += (2.0 * Math.PI * frequency) / (samples_per_second)` (I think that's right)

Comment: Roger, I'll give that a try in a bit.

Comment: The downside is having to keep state, but I can't see any other way.

Comment: That won't be a problem. Will give a try now and post an update as soon as I have some results.